# How to access the column/row info of existing content of a xlsx file

Tags: ruby, xlsx, rubyxl

I want to get the info of the last column and row of an existing xlsx file so that I can append new contents right below the existing content. How do I do so with RubyXL? If that's not possible, what alternative gem would you recommend?

Comment: What docs did you follow?

Comment: Jagdeep: I read the readme and the worksheet page of the manual. I also checked .methods to see which method looks promising, but to no avail. Do you know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I mean can you post the link for me and others to see?

Comment: With this `table = worksheet.map {|row| row && row.cells.each { |cell| cell.value != nil}}` you can build an array reflecting the sheet content, then find where data ends and add your content. If that's your question. Or you can add more details to your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for:

```
require 'rubyXL'

workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("Workbook1.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook[0]

rows = worksheet.map {|row| row && row.cells.each { |cell| cell && cell.value != nil}}
p last_row = rows.size
p last_column = rows.compact.max_by{|row| row.size}.size
```

Comment: This works great for my purpose! I would've repped you but I'm too new. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks. Consider to edit a bit your post to be clearer and searchable for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Let `worksheet` be the first (e.g. `worksheet = workbook[0]`).

You could use:

```
last_row = worksheet.count
last_col = worksheet.map{|i| i.cells.count}.max
```